# stata: inequality constraint in xttobit

Tags: stata

Is it possible to constrain parameters in Stata's `xttobit` to be non-negative? I read a paper where the authors said they did just that, and I am trying to work out how.

I know that you can constrain parameters to be strictly positive by exponentially transforming the variables (e.g. `gen x1_e = exp(x1)`) and then calling `nlcom` after estimation (e.g. `nlcom exp(_b[x1:_y])` where `y` is the independent variable. (That may not be exactly right, but I am pretty sure the general idea is correct. [Here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1328609-non-negative-parameter-constraints-nlsur) is a similar question from Statlist re: `nlsur`).

But what would a non-negative constraint look like? I know that one way to proceed is by transforming the variables, for example squaring them. However, I tried this with the author's data and still found negative estimates from `xttobit`. Sorry if this is a trivial question, but it has me a little confused.

(Note: this was first posted on CV by mistake. Mea culpa.)

Update: It seems I misunderstand what transformation means. Suppose we want to estimate the following random effects model:

y_{it} = a + b*x_{it} + v_i + e_{it}

where v_i is the individual random effect for i and e_{it} is the idiosyncratic error.

From the first answer, would, say, an exponential transformation to constrain all coefficients to be positive look like:

y_{it} = exp(a) + exp(b)*x_{it} + v_i + e_{it}

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of constraining parameters by transforming the associated variable is incorrect. You don't transform the *variable*, but rather you fit your model having reexpressed your model in terms of transformed *parameters*. For more details, see the FAQ at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/regression-with-interval-constraints/, and be prepared to work harder on your problem than you might have expected to, since you will need to replace the use of `xttobit` with `mlexp` for the transformed parameterization of the tobit log-likelihood function.

With regard to the difference between non-negative and strictly positive constraints, for continuous parameters all such constraints are effectively non-negative, because (for reasonable parameterization) a strictly positive constraint can be made arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: Thanks! I added an equation to see if I understand what you mean by transformation. Is that correct? And could you explain the second part about "reasonable parameterization"? For example, does exponential transformation of the parameters count as a reasonable non-negative constraint?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Something like parameters restricted to integer values would be "not reasonable", for example. (3) Yes.